# Calculating the sum of an infinite series (high school calc)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm looking to calculate the sum of the following infinite series:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+5)}$$

and I'm not too sure where to begin. There doesn't seem to be a common ratio. I have tried working it out by dividing it into partial fractions, but this got me nowhere. What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: telescoping sum? use partial fractions.

Comment: How should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write $$\frac{4}{(n+1)(n+5)} = \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+5}$$ writing $n = 0, 1, 2, \cdots$ we get

$\begin{align}
\frac4{1\cdot 5} &= \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{5}\\
\frac4{2\cdot 6} &= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{6}\\
\frac4{3 \cdot 7} &= \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{7}\\
\frac4{4\cdot 8} &= \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{8}\\
\frac4{5 \cdot 9} &= \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{9}\\
\cdots
\end{align}$

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{n = \infty}\frac{4}{(n+1)(n+5)}=1+\frac12 +\frac13+\frac14  $$

Answer (score 4):

$\frac1{(n+1)(n+5)}
=\frac14 (\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+5})
$.

Use this to get
$\sum_{n=1}^m \frac1{(n+1)(n+5)}
$
and let $m \to \infty$.

(added later to explain more fully)

Let
$s_m
=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac1{(n+1)(n+5)}
$,
where $m > 5$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
s_m
&=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac1{(n+1)(n+5)}\\
&=\frac14 \sum_{n=1}^m (\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+5})\\
&=\frac14 \sum_{n=1}^m \frac1{n+1}- \frac14 \sum_{n=1}^m \frac1{n+5}\\
&=\frac14 \sum_{n=2}^{m+1} \frac1{n}- \frac14 \sum_{n=6}^{m+5} \frac1{n}\\
&=\frac14 \left(\sum_{n=2}^{m+1} \frac1{n}-  \sum_{n=6}^{m+5} \frac1{n}\right)\\
&=\frac14 \left(\sum_{n=2}^{5} \frac1{n}+\sum_{n=6}^{m+1} \frac1{n}\right)-  \frac14 \left(\sum_{n=6}^{m+1} \frac1{n}+\sum_{n=m+2}^{m+5} \frac1{n}\right)\\
&=\frac14 \left(\sum_{n=2}^{5} \frac1{n}\right)-  \frac14 \left(\sum_{n=m+2}^{m+5} \frac1{n}\right)
\quad\text{(the common sums cancel)}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=m+2}^{m+5} \frac1{n}
= 0
$
(since it is less than
$\frac{4}{m}$),
$\lim_{m \to \infty} s_m
=\frac14 \sum_{n=2}^{5} \frac1{n}
$.

Comment: This is where I have already gotten. I just don't know how to apply (a/1-r) to solve.

Comment: Dropping the $1/4$, we have $(1/2 - 1/6) + (1/3 - 1/7) + (1/4 - 1/8) + (1/5 - 1/9) + (1/6 - 1/10) + (1/7 - 1/11) + (1/8 - 1/12) + ...$ Note that starting with $1/6$, terms cancel. So all you are left with is the first four terms: $1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5$

Comment: I added a complete explanation.